# Centos https endless loading

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, redmine

I have OS **CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)**, **Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)**, **Redmine v3.4.6**. My site works nice with http, but I want add https support to it. But when I try use https it has endless loading in my browser and then error: *This site can’t be reached took too long to respond.*
I checked my open ports with:

```
sudo netstat -tulnp
```

I can see here: 
[image]
Also I checked it with:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --list-all
```

I can see here:
[image]

My *iptables.service not is inactive (dead)*. I thought that problem was in SELinux, I tried set setenforce to 0, but it did not improve the situation, so I returned setenforce to 1. I test my httpd config - no errors only:
*WARNING: PassengerRoot cannot occur within  section
Syntax OK*

I set *LogLevel debug* in my httpd.conf. But I don't have any error in my logs, moreover as I see on logs with ssl everything is all right:
[image]

Here is my .conf for my site:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Redirect permanent / https://myservernamehere/
    ServerName myservernamehere
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin admin@myservernamehere
    ServerName myservernamehere

    DocumentRoot /home/redmine/redmine_ftp/public

    PassengerRoot /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-6.0.0
    PassengerRuby /usr/local/bin/ruby
    PassengerUser redmine

    <Directory /home/redmine/redmine_ftp/public>
      Allow from all
      Options -MultiViews
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
    PassengerAppEnv production
    PassengerHighPerformance on

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/myservernamehere-0001/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/myservernamehere-0001/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/myservernamehere-0001/chain.pem


    SSLProtocol             all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLHonorCipherOrder     on
    SSLCipherSuite          ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS

    <IfModule headers_module>
        Header always edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure
        Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains"
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

So problem not in SELinux, ports are open, no errors in logs.

> Updated
>   It's not about Apache or Ningh or Redmine, even on a simple standard page, https does not work.

Comment: Can you try running `openssl s_client -connect [your-domain-name]:443` and add the output here?

Comment: @Haxiel I got `socket: Bad file descriptor
connect:errno=9`

Comment: That looks like a connectivity problem rather than an SSL problem. You seem to be listening on IPv6, so hopefully you have already accounted for that. From a remote host, can you try `nc -v hostname 443` or `telnet hostname 443` and see if it connects?

Comment: @Haxiel I got `Connection timed out`

Comment: Can you confirm that you want to use IPv6 here, and that your network is configured to handle it?

Comment: @Haxiel Enough for me Ipv4. I can not confirm that my network can handle it - since it was not I who initially set it up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88080/discussion-between-vladimir-and-haxiel).